# NoClassDefFoundError being thrown when using custom library

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar

I'm using jaudiotagger for an Android app I'm working on - I added the library into eclipse by going into the project properties, and importing the external jar file. I added the correct import statements in my code and have no compile time problems, but when I run the app, a `NoClassDefFoundError` is thrown when i try to create an instance of a class in jaudiotagger. (AudioFile) Is there something further that needs to be done to ensure an external library is installed along with the app?

Here's the line throwing the exception:

```
AudioFile a = AudioFileIO.read(files.get(i));
```

I have the following imports from jaudiotagger:

```
import org.jaudiotagger.audio.AudioFile;
import org.jaudiotagger.audio.AudioFileIO;
```

Comment: is it a jar or a library project?

Comment: assuming jar: is the jarfile of the library in the `libs` folder? Any build messages (for example builds may succeed if you have Java 7 class files in the jar, but they are not properly converted to dex in older versions of the sdk)

Comment: @Raghunandan It's a JAR.

Comment: @Wilson have you added jar to projects libs folder. goto properties. java build path check the order export tab check private libraries.

Comment: Since this an Android application, is there anything Android-specific you have to do to make sure it gets included in the APK?

Comment: @Raghunandan I just needed to check that, thanks so much! If you'd like to submit an answer, I can accept it.